# Getting specific characters from a string and appending them to a list

Tags: python, counter

I have a string that follows:

my_string = "Jack could not **account for** his foolish mistake. Computers **account for** 5% of the country'scommercial electricity consumption. It's time to **focus on** the company's core business. The company needs to **focus on** its biggest clients..."

and a list:

Phrasal_Verbs = [
"account for",
"ache for",
"act on",
"act out",
"act up",
"add on",
"focus on"
...]

I want to find how many occurences each phrasal verbs has in the string with counter module and delete the phrasal verb from the string. My code so far is:

```
phrasal_verbs_list = []
for pv in Phrasal_Verbs:
if pv in my_string:
    phrasal_verbs_list.append(pv)
    my_string = my_string.replace(pv, "")
pv_count = dict(Counter(phrasal_verbs_list))
```

The code above finds all of the phrasal verbs but even if there are three 'Account for's in the string, it gives me only one.

Expected pv_count = {'account for' : 2, 'focus on' : 2, rest_of_the_phrasal_verbs : occurrences }

Got = {'account for': 1, 'act out': 1, 'allow for': 1, 'be in': 1, 'be on': 1, 'blow down': 1, ... 'focus on' : 1}

Comment: What's your question exactly? Do you want to know how to fix your current implementation, or would you be open to a better implementation? Also, for clarity it'd help to provide a [mre] including exact inputs, exact expected output, and actual output. For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply do this

```
pv_count = {string: my_string.count(string) for string in Phrasal_Verbs}
```

And then, if you want to remove the phrasal verbs from the string:

```
import re
text = re.sub("|".join(pv_count.keys()), "", my_string)
```

You could also call `Phrasal_Verbs` directly instead of `pv_count.keys() pointed out in the comments.

Comment: `pv_count.keys()` is the same as `Phrasal_Verbs` by definition, unless you were to do an intermediate step to remove 0 counts.

Comment: Good point.  I guess it would be more efficient to call Phrasal_Verbs directly but I will leave it because, as you said, one may want to go this route if one wants to transform `pv_count` further.

Comment: That substitution may not work properly if any `Phrasal_Verbs` overlap, for example, `"be in", "be into"`. OP's example doesn't contain any like that, but it's still something to watch out for. I think you could fix it with word bounds: `r'\b(' + '|'.join(pv_count.keys()) + r')\b'`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `replace` replaces all occurrences of that string and therefore, the remaining occurrences won't be counted resulting in a count of 1.

Use `my_string.replace(pv, "", 1)` to only replace the first occurrence. That should fix your problem.